# Detect Carriage return in a string

Tags: c#

I have he following issue:

```
String line = @"Line1
            Line2
            Line3
            Line4";
```

I am trying to create a loop that detects when the carriage return character is encountered and store each row on a separate string.

```
String value    
static long LinesCount(string s)
        {
        long count = 0;
        int position = 0;
        while ((position = s.IndexOf('\n', position)) != -1)
            {
            count++;           
            }
        return count;
        }

for (int i = 1; i > LinesCount(line); i++)
        {
            value = line.Split(Environment.NewLine)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to create a loop that detects when the carriage return character is encountered and store each row on a separate string.

just split `line` by `'\n'` character. resulting array contains expected rows

```
String line = @"Line1
    Line2
    Line3
    Line4";
string[] lines = line.Split('\n');
foreach(var L in lines)
{
    Console.Write(L);
    Console.WriteLine(';'); // for demonstration purpose
}
```

console output

```
Line1;
            Line2;
            Line3;
            Line4;
```

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MVqqhW)